# String of hexadecimal numbers don't align properly in tabular cell

Tags: tables, fonts, spacing, cell

The code below

```
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
    \hline
        $C_2$ & B5 6E 2C D4 F3 12 57 3E 8C 8C 1A 77 A3 EE C3 41 \\ 
        $P'_3 \xor P_3$ & 00 00 00 00 00 0F 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \\
        C'_2$ & B5 6E 2C D4 F3 1D 57 3D 8C 8C 1A 77 A3 EE C3 41\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Produces the autrocity that is this:
[image: Second row of 0's does not look proper]

I have tried different alignments, fonts and font sizes. Please help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Changing the second alignment (since you only have two columns) to `l` should give the desired results?  For future reference, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Will know for the future, Thanks @peter-grill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not too difficult if your editor supports replace all in selection.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\xor{\oplus}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ |c| r*{15}{@{ }r}| }
    \hline
        $C_2$ & B5 & 6E & 2C &  D4 & F3 & 12 & 57 & 3E & 8C & 8C & 1A & 77 & A3 & EE & C3 & 41 \\ 
        $P'_3 \xor P_3$ & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 0F & 00 & 03 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 & 00 \\
        $C'_2$ & B5 & 6E & 2C & D4 & F3 & 1D & 57 & 3D & 8C & 8C & 1A & 77 & A3 & EE & C3 & 41\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, how to avoid changing the input with so many `&`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not necessary with LaTeX 2020-10-01
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcommand{\xor}{\oplus}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bytetable}{O{\textwidth}m}
 {
  \dutt_bytetable:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \l__dutt_bytetable_bytes_int
\seq_new:N \l__dutt_bytetable_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__dutt_bytetable_row_seq
\seq_new:N \l__dutt_bytetable_bytes_seq
\tl_new:N \l__dutt_bytetable_temp_tl
\tl_new:N \l__dutt_bytetable_body_tl

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nne }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dutt_bytetable:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__dutt_bytetable_rows_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  % examine the part after the last \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__dutt_bytetable_rows_seq \l__dutt_bytetable_temp_tl
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__dutt_bytetable_temp_tl
   {% not empty, reinsert
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__dutt_bytetable_rows_seq \l__dutt_bytetable_temp_tl
   }
  % let's build the body of the table
  \tl_clear:N \l__dutt_bytetable_body_tl
  \int_zero:N \l__dutt_bytetable_bytes_int % this counts the number of bytes
  % examine each row
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__dutt_bytetable_rows_seq
   {
    % separate the parts before and after &
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__dutt_bytetable_row_seq { & } { ##1 }
    % in the second part we need to split at spaces
    \seq_set_split:Nne \l__dutt_bytetable_bytes_seq { ~ }
     {
      \seq_item:Nn \l__dutt_bytetable_row_seq { 2 }
     }
    % count the number of parts in the bytes section
    \int_set:Nn \l__dutt_bytetable_bytes_int
     {
      \int_max:nn { \l__dutt_bytetable_bytes_int } { \seq_count:N \l__dutt_bytetable_bytes_seq }
     }
    % add the row to the table
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__dutt_bytetable_body_tl
     {
      % first the part before &
      \seq_item:Nn \l__dutt_bytetable_row_seq { 1 } &
      % then the rest, with & in between each item
      \seq_use:Nn \l__dutt_bytetable_bytes_seq { & }
      % the endline marker
      \exp_not:N \\
     }
   }
  % output the table
  \group_begin:
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{#1}
   {
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{$}c<{$}
    *{\l__dutt_bytetable_bytes_int}{c}
   }
  \toprule
  \l__dutt_bytetable_body_tl
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\bytetable{
  C_2           & B5 6E 2C D4 F3 12 57 3E 8C 8C 1A 77 A3 EE C3 41 \\ 
  P'_3 \xor P_3 & 00 00 00 00 00 0F 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \\
  C'_2          & B5 6E 2C D4 F3 1D 57 3D 8C 8C 1A 77 A3 EE C3 41 \\
}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\bytetable` command has an optional argument for the width of the final table, default is `\textwidth`.

If the number of bytes is small in some instances, it should not be difficult to allow for the table to be at its natural size without manual intervention. Of course, if the number of bytes is large, there would be clashes, depending on the overall text width.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, perhaps you should be using a fixed width font for hexadecimal numbers, e.g. `\texttt`.  In the table context you can use the features from the standard `array` package to add formatting to the corresponding column:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c>{\ttfamily}c}
    \hline
        $C_2$ & B5 6E 2C D4 F3 12 57 3E 8C 8C 1A 77 A3 EE C3 41 \\
        $P'_3 \oplus P_3$ & 00 00 00 00 00 0F 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \\
        $C'_2$ & B5 6E 2C D4 F3 1D 57 3D 8C 8C 1A 77 A3 EE C3 41\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[I have changed `\xor` to `\oplus` just for my own convenience.]